# Faulty proof of Lagrange Multipliers?

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry, optimization, convex-analysis, lagrange-multiplier

i am currently reading the book [Convex Analysis](https://www.springer.com/de/book/9783030418038). At "Theorem 7.8.1" there is given a sketch of a proof which seems faulty to me. I will briefly explain the Theorem and the proof and then my problem i have. Maybe you can hint me where i missed something.

We start out as usual with continuous differerentiable functions $f_0,\dots,f_m : U\to \mathbb R$ with $U\subset \mathbb R^n$ open.

If the following Problem has a minimum at $\hat x$:

$\min f_0(x), x\in \mathbb R^n,\ f_1(x) = \dots = f_m(x) =0$

Then there exists $\lambda = \lambda_0,\dots,\lambda_m$ , not all $0$ with:

$\mathcal L(\hat x,\lambda) = \lambda_0 f'_0(\hat x) + \dots + \lambda_m f'_m(\hat x) = 0$

The proof thats shown in the book goes like this: (you may skip this part at first glance)

Let $\hat x$ be a minimal point of the Problem. Define $F(x,y) = f_0(x) \text{ if } f_1(x) +y_1 = \dots = f_m(x) + y_m = 0$ and $\infty$ otherwise. For $$\min f(x) := F(x,0)$$ we get our original Problem then. Taking the solutionset of $(z,y) = (f_0(x),\dots, f_m(x))$ we can define a function $g(x)=(z,y)$ which is continuously differnentiable and its Graph ,,can be seen'' as the Graph $\Gamma_F$ of $F$ (This is sort of wrong already but since its a sketch i get what he means). Now the author says the Tangent space $T_{(\hat x, 0_Y, f(\hat x))}$ at the  $(\hat x, 0 , f(\hat x))(\Gamma_F)$ then is the Graph of the derivative $g'(\hat x)x = (f_0'(\hat x)x, \dots, f_m'(\hat x)x)$ so we can describe it by an equation
$$
\langle (\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_m),y\rangle -\langle \lambda_0,z\rangle = 0
$$

And like this we get the multiplicators. **Now comes the part where it seems wrong to me**:
We want $y$ to be $0$ to solve our problem $\min f(x) = F(x,0)$ and also $z$ to be $0$ for minimality sake which translates into
$$
(\mathbb R^n \times 0_Y \times 0) + T_{(\hat x, 0_Y, f(\hat x))} \subsetneq \mathbb R^n \times Y\times \mathbb R
$$
note the proper inclusion is equivalent to $(\mathbb R^n \times 0_Y \times 0)\subset T_{(\hat x, 0_Y, f(\hat x))}$. **BUT** why would $z$ be $0$?. The Author says because Tangent space of the Graph of $f$ at the point $(\hat x, f(\hat x))$ is contained in $\mathbb R^n\times 0$, ,,which follows immediatly from the local minimality of $f$''. But that thing is not even differentiable by definition. I mean okay one could go with the subgradient instead or something. But still its wrong in my opinion. I mean imagine $n=2$ and $f_0$ to be  an inverse Paraboloid and $f_1 = 0$ is our only restriction which is $0$ on the unit ball, smooth and $>0$ outside the unit ball. Then the subgradient $\partial f(x)$ will never have an element $0$ inside its [subgradient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subderivative). Even in this more general case its wrong right?

Comment: I haven't studied this carefully, but you're right that it seems suspicious. Moreover, the statement omits the crucial hypothesis that the constraint equations are independent, which is what you need to know that the constraint set is actually a submanifold. Once you have the correct statement, you then need to apply the implicit function theorem in some way to give a proof.

Comment: Do you mean that the $f'_n$ should be independent?

Comment: I think it actually works for the subgradient atleast. I thought a bit about but in the case of $f_0$ beeing a paraboloid and $f_1$ the indicator for the unit ball then the subgradient of $f(x)$ on the edge of the ball at some point will have $0$ in it because outside the ball $f(x)$ will be infinity. I think like this one could fix the argumentation if one also would use the more general concept of a tangent cone instead of tangent space.

Comment: Yes, the $f_1,\dots,f_m$ have to be linearly independent. You can certainly make up examples where L.M. fails if they are not.

Comment: if they are not independent one can always find a non trivial $\lambda$ so that $\lambda_0 f'_0 + \dots + \lambda_m f'_m = 0$

Comment: That doesn’t convince me that L.M. necessarily fails. It’s just giving me the definition.

Comment: I wouldnt say it fails. I would rather say that the implication becomes trivial. Maybe i dont understand what you mean by failing though.

Comment: You are looking for constrained critical points of $f_0$. The linear independence is on $f_1’,\dots,f_m’$. You should read a more traditional advanced calculus source.

Comment: Can you name me a good one?

I also noticed that the $\lambda$ actually depends on $\hat x$. That shouldnt be right? 
In the convex case that would work though since there is a unique minimum or the function to be minimized is locally linear around $\hat x$.

Comment: I'm fond of my own text, of course. You might also check out the relevant ones of my YouTube lectures. All linked in my profile.

Comment: Oh okay. I will definitely check them out soon. Thanks!